# Why Lucene result contains only exact matches?

Tags: java, lucene

I've created an index of documents in Lucene. One of the field is named `title` and I want to search for all documents which `title` contains `word`. Unfortunately I only get the exact result - I get document with a title `word` (but not e.g. `my word`).

Code:

```
    String field = "title";
    String value = "word"; 
    List<MyDoc> myDocList = new ArrayList<MyDoc>();
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_45);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_45, field, analyzer);

         try {

             Query query = new TermQuery(new Term(field, value));
            int numResults = 100;
            ScoreDoc[] hits =   indexSearcher.search(query,numResults).scoreDocs;
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                 Document doc = indexSearcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
                 myDocList .add(getMyDoc(doc));
            }

         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace(); 
         }

         return myDocList ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how the index was created. It sounds like you might have used a StringField instead of a TextField. I don't think a StringField tokenizes its contents, instead treating it like one big keyword.

Comment: Yes, I used StringField. Didn't know that could be a problem. Thanks